# How to remove specific response body content in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

How Remove specific response body field content in Elasticsearch response.

My response body from Elasticsearch is,

```
{
  "took": 67,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 331,
    "successful": 331,
    "skipped": 321,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 5344,
    "max_score": 4.2037153,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "Test-2018.03.22",
        "_type": "Emp",
        "_id": "df4354yy5465645tytryytI",
        "_score": 4.2037153,
        "_source": {
          "time": "2018-03-22T12:46:39.6259805Z",
          "Sample": "Info",
          "Active": "Avaliable",
          "ProcessCheck1": "0",
          "ProgramId2": "0",
        }
      },
      ]
      }
      }
```

Is there a way to remove them so i can have the following structure,

```
{

  "hits": {
    "total": 5344,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_source": {
          "time": "2018-03-22T12:46:39.6259805Z",
          "Sample": "Info",
        }
      },
      ]
      }
      }
```

Thanks for reading.I will appreciate your help!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope it will help you:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/Test-2018.03.22/_search?_source=time,Sample&filter_path=hits.total,hits.hits._source&pretty'
```

In `_source` you can specify all fields comma separated.

Comment: ,Thanks for response ,But i want  "total": 5344, field also please check my post.